# App crashes when 'not' selecting an image from file choose / gallery

Tags: java, android

When I try to select an image the filechooser shows 'camera' and 'files', if I do not select one and click away, it crashes?
I have tried a few answers but I am a webdev not android dev. Help!

This is similar to [app crashes when going back from gallery without selecting any image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26115623/app-crashes-when-going-back-from-gallery-without-selecting-any-image)

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode != INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE || mUploadMessage == null) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        return;
    }
    try {
        String file_path = mCameraPhotoPath.replace("file:","");
        File file = new File(file_path);
        size = file.length();

    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("Error!", "Error while opening image file" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    if (data != null || mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
        Integer count = 1;
        ClipData images = null;
        try {
            images = data.getClipData();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error!", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        if (images == null && data != null && data.getDataString() != null) {
                count = data.getDataString().length();
        } else if (images != null) {
                count = images.getItemCount();
        }
        Uri[] results = new Uri[count];
        // Check that the response is a good one
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (size != 0) {
                // If there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                if (mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath)};
                }
            } else if (data.getClipData() == null) {
                results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(data.getDataString())};
            } else {

                for (int i = 0; i < images.getItemCount(); i++) {
                    results[i] = images.getItemAt(i).getUri();
                }
            }
        }

        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(results);
        mUploadMessage = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Update your question with the error you are receiving

Answer (score 5):

You haven't done any `resultCode` oriented check in your `onActivityResult` before doing your computation. As when you come back without selecting the image, resultCode is `RESULT_CANCELLED` and your `data` is null. Post that any operation on your `data` will always result in a null pointer exception

do as follows -

```
if (resultCode==RESULT_OK){
  // do stuff here that is the part of your try catch block
}
```

mostly your code is crashing when you try to do data.getDataString() on a data which is not there. And also considering this is outside your try block it never gets caught and app crashes.

Comment: `mCameraPhotoPath.replace("file:","")` is also dangerous if not storred in `Bundle` when activity killed

Comment: There is one. It's near the end and probably to late to do it but there is one

Comment: Yeah i saw it now. Way too late. Thanks @litelite

Comment: Ok I have added your code, which does indeed stop the app crashing... but when I click the button to add an image again, and show the file chooser it does not fire up any more. Any thoughts....

Comment: Still Not Fixed !!! My choice is either let the app crash OR once it shows no error on no chosen file, it will not show the file chooser again! Maybe it needs the variables resetting again.  How do I re-enable the file chooser again????

Comment: And also the updated code for this method. want to understand what is common between both that is causing this issue