# Android kotlin - app stopps working when gallery selection is cancelled

Tags: java, android, kotlin

This is the code:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload_image)

        but.setOnClickListener {
            chooseImage()
        }

    }

    fun chooseImage(){
        val intent = Intent()
        intent.type = "image/*"
        intent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 1)
    }

public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        // do stuff
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "CANCELLED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

I got the `requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null` from: [app crashes when going back from gallery without selecting any image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26115623/app-crashes-when-going-back-from-gallery-without-selecting-any-image) because there was the same problem, but this solution isn't working by me, The app crashes when I tab the back button on the phone instead of selecting image. Do I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When action is cancelled then `data` will be `null`(returned by the gallery app)  but Kotlin doesn't allow `null` by default so hence the issue.

To avoid that, set `data` as nullable using `?` as `Intent?`

```
public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int,
               resultCode: Int,
               data: Intent?) {
// mark as null type       ^
```

Comment: That's it thanks! The whole "null safety" is the only thing I find annoying by kotlin :D

Comment: all I can say is, we get used to it, glad to help, happy coding!